# Symfony2.3 - how to authenticate in iframe

Tags: php, symfony, iframe, authentication

I have an external page with an iframe, in which a specific Symfony page is supposed to load. Unfortunately, the page requires a login, so I tried to create an invisible form with _password and _username that submits to the iframe as target:

```
<form target="theiframe" id="theiframe" name="frameform" method="post" action="http://someurl.com/login_check">
<input type="hidden" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="User" value="theusername" required="" autofocus="">
<input type="hidden" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Passwort" value="thepassword" required="">
</form>
<iframe width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" name="theiframe" id="theiframe" src=""></iframe>
```

But for some reason, when I try this, Symfony redirects me to the login form with an error:

```
Your session has timed out, or you have disabled cookies.
```

As soon as I reload the page, it suddenly works. It's only the first try that fails.

Is there a way to fix this? How?

Comment: can you post that external_page code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to secure.yml in your external_page symfony2. And add this :

```
secured_area:
    ...
    form_login:
        ...
        require_previous_session: false
```